# Optimizing CPU usage of a CSS animation using translateX

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm making some silly little animation. First I did the animation in JavaScript, which predictably had horrible performance. Then I tried to reproduce it with CSS animations, thinking that would be use less CPU. It does perform better, but it still uses a bit more CPU than I'd like. So my question is, does anyone have any ideas for how to most efficiently implement this simple animation?

```js
const bars = document.getElementById("top").children;

const colorMap = {
  0: 3,
  1: 4,
  2: 5,
  3: 0,
  4: 1,
  5: 2,
};
const getDuration = () => 1000 + Math.random() * 4000;
function makeBubble(bar, i) {
  const bubble = document.createElement("div");

  bubble.style.animationDuration = `${getDuration()}ms`;
  bubble.classList.add("bubble");
  bubble.classList.add(`top-${colorMap[i]}`);

  bubble.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    bar.removeChild(bubble);
    makeBubble(bar, i);
  });

  bar.appendChild(bubble);
}

// Initialize bubbles
for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
  makeBubble(bars[i], i);
}
```

```css
#top div {
  height: 0.75em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#top .top-0 {
  background-color: #4c22c8
}
#top .top-1 {
  background-color: #6c49d1
}
#top .top-2 {
  background-color: #8b70da
}
#top .top-3 {
  background-color: #aa97e3
}
#top .top-4 {
  background-color: #cabeec
}
#top .top-5 {
  background-color: #e9e5f5
}
@keyframes move-bubble {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
#top .bubble {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.0, 1, 0.75);
  animation-name: move-bubble;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div class="top-0"></div>
  <div class="top-1"></div>
  <div class="top-2"></div>
  <div class="top-3"></div>
  <div class="top-4"></div>
  <div class="top-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Offtopic: Don't take this serious [HTML 5 animation to GIF](https://html5animationtogif.com/) got it from [Can i convert HTML+CSS animation to .gif extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550758/can-i-convert-htmlcss-animation-to-gif-extension)

Comment: That would work, except there is some randomness in my animation which I'd like to keep :)

Comment: Ontopic: CSS animation on modern browsers should be GPU accelerated .. Atleast when you add `transform: translateZ(0);` ..  crossbrowser `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: I tried `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` and `transform: translate3d(100vw, 0, 0);` (rather than `translateZ` because I already am moving it in the x dimension) but I don't notice any difference. Guess it could also be cause I'm on Linux, I know GPU acceleration stuff is often weird there.

Comment: the translateZ method is a "hack" to create a new layer. This new layer can then be moved by the gpu instead of repainting the point every time. The official way to do this is using the will-change property, e.g. in your case `will-change: transform`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of `will-change`! That also seems to not make a difference, though.

Comment: [Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)  maybe giving [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap/) a try?    Check that JS [performance](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/srfxA) vs jQuery  .. But be sure to check it's [License](https://greensock.com/licensing/)